# Handling char* in C# (strlen function?)

Tags: c#, c++, character-encoding, strlen, arrays

I'm dealing with a char* in C# code (in an unsafe section). Is there any way to call the strlen function from C#. It goes against all common sense to have to write a custom strlen function to search for the null terminator. Isn't there a way to call strlen from C# or a similar method that I have access to?

In the big picture I'm trying to convert the char* to a string object, but the characters are in ANSCII format, so I'm going to use the .NET Encoding.Convert namespace to convert it. But I need to know the length of the string before I do that.

Comment: @dlev I'm getting this char* from the Scintilla environment so I don't have control over it. I don't get the length directly, but I can calculate it from some other stuff. I just thought that there must be a way to do an equivalent of strlen in C# if they let you handle char*. I know I'm not the first person to think of this.

Comment: `char` is two bytes wide, so if your `char*` points to single-byte data, you may not find a null terminator at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) does exactly what you need:

> Allocates a managed String and copies all characters up to the first
>   null character from a string stored in unmanaged memory into it.

Incidentally, the method calls `lstrlenA` on the pointer, which is actually just an import from `kernel32.dll`. In other words, there does *not* appear to be a managed "get me the length of this unmanaged string" method available.

Comment: +1 good point, but the data has to have some null termination character (its presence is not mandatory). Need to be check if this ok for OP.

Comment: @Tigran the OP's requirement assumes the existence of a null termination character.  He presumably understands the risk of bad data causing an access violation.

Comment: @Tigran I am assuming a null-terminator is present. If there is a case where it isn't I'll get to know fairly quickly but it apparently always is.